# Job Alert Notification when Job fails X times

Tags: sql-server, jobs

It is possible to configure a Notification Alert rule for SQL Jobs that notify only when fails X times? I have a SQL Job that executes each X minutes and it's not important if fails one or two times but I'm interesting in notify when fails 5 consecutive times.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the way you describe it, but it can be done.

Create another job which will run periodically and check if the  condition was met. If it was, raise an error to notify operator.

The actual query would look something like this:

```
if (
    select sum(run_status) 
    from (
        select top (5) *
        from 
        [dbo].[sysjobhistory]
        where step_id = 0
        and job_id = 'id_of_your_job'
        order by run_date desc, run_time desc
    ) x
) > 0
raiserror ('The job failed last five times.', 16, 1)
```